# Extract TFS 2012 build unit test results

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know of a way to quickly get at the unit test results of a build in TFS2012?

Currently I have to find the build in visual studio and collapse the various other nodes in the summary as shown in the screenshot below. Then I have to expand each set of results to get at the failures. I just want a list of all failed tests.

I'd be happy to use SQL, SQL Reporting services or even a text file from the build.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TFS API to get the test result. Check the code snippet below:

```
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/collectionname"));
    tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

    IBuildServer tfsBuildServer = tfs.GetService<IBuildServer>();

    IBuildDefinition buildDef = tfsBuildServer.GetBuildDefinition("teamproject", "project");

    var BuildUri = buildDef.LastBuildUri;

    ITestManagementService testManagement = (ITestManagementService)tfs.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
    ITestManagementTeamProject testManagementTeamProject = testManagement.GetTeamProject("teamproject");
    IEnumerable<ITestRun> testRuns = testManagementTeamProject.TestRuns.ByBuild(BuildUri);


    foreach (ITestRun testRun in testRuns)
    {
        foreach (ITestCaseResult result in testRun.QueryResults())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("TestCaseID:{0}", result.TestCaseTitle.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("TestCaseOutcome:{0}", result.Outcome.ToString()));
        }
    }
```